# How do I securely client-side cache an encryption password in React/Next?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cryptography

I made a file encryption app that takes a password to encrypt files. I want to cache the password the user typed in client-side, even after page changes, so that they don’t have to keep typing in their password each time they access the encryption page. What’s the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should have no problem storing this as a cookie (just like a session cookie from a login). You **should** additionally encrypt it before setting it as a cookie so that if someone gets hijacked the attacker won't get access to the plaintext password. Also, make sure to set a reasonable expiration on it.

Comment: This won’t work because the server will see the password. I don’t want the server to see the decryption password.

Comment: There aren't really any other options if this is to be entirely client-side. You would still need to set a cookie (or localstorage) but wouldn't be able to encrypt it. This is very iffy from a security perspective, but client-siding an entire process like this puts the control completely into the users hands (including keeping that plaintext password cookie safe)

Comment: There are apps like Bitwarden that seem to do this without localstorage or cookie storage of the password. Do you know how they do it?

Comment: @amazingdoodler Bitwarden is a browser addon, so it extends functionality of the browser that **cannot** be done with client-side javascript code. (If you wanted to use a similar approach, you would need to create your own browser plugin that users download to use your website that locally encrypts their passwords. Every user would need your browser addon for this to work). Additionally, Bitwarden stores user passwords on the **server** side of things. The users password is encrypted locally on their machine and then sent to a cloud database for storage.

Comment: Well I was talking about the web vault. It requires no extension, and the user's encryption password is cached *somewhere* because it doesn't require you to sign in again, even after a page change (like going to Settings from Vault).

Comment: @amazingdoodler No the user password is not cached anywhere. The encryption key is derived by using hash functions on your master password locally, then sent to their server where it is stored in its encrypted form alongside vault data. The vault is located in Microsoft Azure cloud. As far as data persistence, they use sessions when you login. A session is stored on their server which is why you don't have to sign in again. IE, for the duration of the session they are storing your encrypted password on their server